# Error in VSCode, while i try create a spotify discord bot: [ SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module ] with node.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, spotify

I can't execute and debug my discord bot, having an error in debugging console.

This is my code in the bot:

```
const discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new discord.Client({
    ws: { intents: discord.Intents.ALL },
});

import spotify from 'spotify-web-api-js';
const spotifyAPI = new spotify();

import { MessageEmbed } from 'discord.js';

//Spotify Credentials
spotifyAPI.setAccessToken('HIDDEN');

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('!play')) {
        let songName = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
        spotifyAPI.searchTracks(songName)
        .then(function(data) {
            let song = data.tracks.items[0];
            let songName =song.name;
            let songUrl =song.preview_url;
            let songAuthor =song.artists[0].name;
            let songEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`Playing ${songName}`)
            .setURL(songUrl)
            .setAuthor(songAuthor)
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            message.channel.send(songEmbed);
        }, function(err) {
            console.error(err);
            message.channel.send("Sorry, I couldn't find the song you requested. Please try again with a different name or check your internet connection.");
        });
    }
});

client.login('HIDDEN');
```

And i have this error in my debugging console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\Proyectos de VS Code\spoticord\spoticord.js:6
import spotify from 'spotify-web-api-js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at compileFunction (vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1088:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1123:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at <anonymous> (internal/main/run_main_module:23:47)
Process exited with code 1
```

I tried update discord.js, spotify-web-api-js, reinstall both modules.
But gives another errors like:

- TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ALL')
- SyntaxError: Identifier 'Discord' has already been declared
- Valid intents must be provided for the Client.

Comment: For your information: Spotify doesn't allows the use of its API in Discord bots, because they don't allow [any product or service which is integrated with streams or content from another service](https://developer.spotify.com/policy/#:~:text=Do%20not%20create%20any%20product%20or%20service%20which%20is%20integrated%20with%20streams%20or%20content%20from%20another%20service.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your package's settings are for "CommonJS", when `import` is allowed for "module" types.

```js
// at line 6
import spotify from 'spotify-web-api-js'
// at line 9
// this must be replaced also, like at line 6
import { MessageEmbed } from 'discord.js';
```

There are two correct solutions.

1. Set "type" as "module" in "package.json" and use `import <name> from <module>` instead of `const <name> = require("<module>")`
2. Replace `import spotify from 'spotify-web-api-js';` with `const spotify = require("spotify-web-api-js")`, because "CommonJS" doesn't support "import"